# I have multiple filenames with different versions . how to pick the highest numbered version from every filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have multiple filenames with different versions . how to pick the highest numbered version from every filename .

ex:

```
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-19.04.1111-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-19.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-19.04.1111-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-19.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.12.13-1.el9.x86_64.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.12.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.13.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

O?P:

```
glusterfs-cli-3.13.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Any chance to tell version identitfiers from constant product fields? Is that always two version fields in front of the arch and .rpm fileds?

Comment: yes same noarch.rpm and .rpm

Comment: yes sorry BMS-CEI2_BC-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm this should be in the output :

Comment: Why could `el7` be preferred over `el9`? The selection rule for `glusterfs-cli` is unclear to me.

Comment: `sort -V` should help

Comment: because the last one starts with glusterfs-cli-3.13.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm  [3.13]

Comment: I generally just do `ls -v` (equivalent to `sort -V` which someone already mentioned).  Not sure if it ticks all your needs but it's a good one to remember.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with GNU tools (it's not POSIX) and `bash` or some other array-capable shell

```
#!/bin/bash

# An associative array
declare -A names

# Iterate across the files, stripping version numbers and saving the name/prefix
for file in *.rpm
do
    name=${file%%-[1-9]*}    # Assume "-" and a non-zero digit marks the version
    ((names[$name]++))
done
echo "Prefixes: ${!names[@]}"
echo

# Iterate across the prefixes looking for the highest numbered version
for name in "${!names[@]}"
do
    find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "${name}-[1-9]*.rpm" -printf "%f\0" |
        sort -z -rV |
        head -z -n1 |
        tr '\0' '\n'
done |
    sort
```

Output

```
Prefixes: BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP glusterfs-cli BMS-CEI2_BC

BMS-CEI2_BC-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.13.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

If you can guarantee your filenames contain no newlines you can simplify the `find` segment a little:

```
    find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "${name}-*.rpm" -printf "%f\n" |
        sort -rV |
        head -n1
```

If you don't need to sort the set of names into an order, remove the trailing `| sort`

Comment: help me 
./scrip.sh: line 8: scrip.sh: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".sh")
Prefixes: 0

Comment: It might be that your script that has an `.sh` ending is being processed as well, try chaning the glob to `*.rpm` instead of just `*`

Comment: @yugandhar I've made a couple of tidy-ups so please try the script again. However, I can't see why you would have got that `invalid arithmetic operator` message - are you running it with `bash` or some other shell?

Comment: running in bash

Comment: facing this head -z -n1 |

Comment: head: invalid option -- 'z'
Try `head --help' for more information.

Comment: able to print prefix : but facing error here

Comment: @yugandhar use the "no newlines" option in my answer

Answer (score 1):

This just feels horrible but it works with your data set

```
sed -E "s/^(.+-)(([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+-.*)$/\1 \2/g" file1 | sort -r | awk '$1!=old{print $1$2; old=$1}'
```

Split out the base names with `sed`

`sort` in reverse to bubble the higher versions to the top

`awk` out the first occurrence of each base name, reassembling them as you do.

Output:

```
glusterfs-cli-3.13.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a python script in your case ,something like this a.py:

```
import os
import re
highestFile='a'
files = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if os.path.isfile(f)]

for f in files:
    if highestFile[0]==f[0]: 
        if highestFile<f:
            highestFile=f
    else :
        print(highestFile)
        highestFile=f
```

For example this would work if you files started with different letters ,you can modify line 5 to add a stricter criteria like

```
if highestFile[1]==f[1] and highestFile[0]==f[0]:
```

,would take account of two letters, not the best answer admittedly,but it works.
This script should be contained in the folder of interest and you can run it from terminal with :

```
python3 a.py
```

Comment: you can add these for a better criteria https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-splitting-text-and-number-in-string/